# One single cURL command to delete a GeoServer raster layer (coverage) from a coveragestore via REST

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I have published a GeoTIFF image to a GeoServer coveragestore as a layer.

In order to delete the layer I had to run the following two cURL commands:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE http://localhost:8090/geoserver/rest/layers/{WORKSPACE}:{LAYER}.xml

curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE http://localhost:8090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{WORKSPACE}/coveragestores/{COVERAGESTORE}/coverages/{COVERAGE}.xml
```

I was unable to find any documentation regarding deleting a coverage on GeoServer, so I am wondering if it's possible to just run one command to complete the coverage delete via GeoServer REST.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why do you need it in one command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `?recurse=true` to delete the contain of the store:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE http://localhost:8090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{WORKSPACE}/coveragestores/{COVERAGESTORE}/coverages/{COVERAGE}.xml?recurse=true
```